# One corner never sticks

Tags: adhesion

I am new to 3D printing. I thought that the black surface of my print bed was supposed to keep things stuck without additional tape, spray, etc.  However, every time I print something, this same corner, and only this corner, detaches.

Any advice on how to fix this?

- Monoprice Makerselect V2
- Hatchbox PLA
- Temp 195/50

[image: Photo of print warping in corner]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is very likely caused by an uneven bed. It's probably lower in that particular corner: the nozzle is further from the bed, so the filament isn't squished down as much and therefore releases more easily from the bed.

Your bed should have 3 or 4 screws that you can adjust, you should loosen the screw in the corner that is giving you trouble.

Comment: That seems to be the problem.  The print bed has a significantly low spot in that area.  thanks.

Comment: I'm paranoid, so I often overtape the brim to ensure it doesn't come loose.   You might also consider raising the head temp a bit so the first layer is less viscous and will microflow onto the bed better (more adhesion)

Comment: After trying to deal with this for a while I realized aluminum warps with heat and the print surface will never be flat.  I use a glass plate now and it is much better.